# How to Test Sencha Touch apps in windows

Tags: testing, sencha-touch

So I am developing a Sencha Touch application in Windows. I want to test how this is going to behave on iPhone/Android/BlackBerry phones.

I'd rather not make it public just to test it by navigating to it from each OS physically, although I will be doing that before our official release. How can I emulate the phones on windows. Is there anything I can use to emulate Blackberry/iPhone on a windows machine just to test how the web page is going to be rendered in those devices?

I know the Android emulator I can run through Eclipse, but what about the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Mac to run the iPhone/iPad simulator.  Blackberry can be done on windows though: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/

You might also consider delivering them to these devices as apps using phonegap, which plays nicely with sencha touch.

Comment: Thanks for the Blackberry link. But for PhoneGap, would I be able to build the whole thing in Sencha Touch, wire it up to my existing web site's backend, and just run some PhoneGap process and it would take care of it all? If we make it native, I still want it to access my URL in the WebView.

Comment: Without knowing any more about your project or what you are trying to achieve, what you said is doable with phonegap.  Phonegap just lays the foundation for communicating with mobile platforms and their underlying functional APIs.  Its frameworks like Sencha Touch, jQuery Mobile, XUIJS, etc... that make them actually look the part of a native app.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see how the app would look and behave while developing, just use Google Chrome. You can enable the very good 'developer tools' to do various checks.

Comment: I've been using chrome but, I can never get it resized exactly how I would like to.

Comment: I see what you mean. I had the same problem and ended up giving dimensions to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run on [`Ripple Chrome Extension`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

Check out the number of `devices / platforms` it supports

```
 ... 
 ...
 iPhone 3G / 4     
 iPad
 Nexus One 
 Nexus S  etc..
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to start developing applications using Sencha Touch, it is highly
recommended that you have a working web server where you can host your
application. It's possible to develop Sencha Touch applications, viewing local
folders with your web browser. Without a web server you won't be able to test
your application using any mobile devices.

You can run the application on your web browser by using:

```
http://localhost/your_app_folder
```

Using Safari web browser to examine your Sencha Touch application during
development, and the Safari Web Inspector is a huge part of that. Both Chrome
and Firefox have similar tools (Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug for Firefox),
but as iOS devices use Safari for their web browser.